# PDFsharp in C# document has both color modes CMYK and RGB

Tags: c#, pdf, rgb, pdfsharp, cmyk

In a C# project with PDFsharp (WPF build) I save a PDF document setting

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
document.Options.ColorMode = PdfColorMode.Cmyk;
```

In the document I draw an image stored in another PDF source and a PNG/TIFF image (depends).

When I open the saved document in Adobe Bridge it tells me that both color modes CMYK and RGB are set in the document. How can I make PDFsharp save my document in CMYK only?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all PDF sources used to create the new PDF are set to CMYK. The setting you use applies to new PDF content, but not to pages imported from external source PDFs.

Comment: I double checked. They are all  CMYK. However one TIFF-File is CMYK when loading it - but if I load the resulting PDF in Photoshop and tell PS to open the images in the PDF then the image which source was the TIFF file is set to RGB-mode now...